# onchange event with timestamp posted to local storeage - for team of 7 users

Tags: javascript, html

Okay, I have a team of 7 people and I need to make this code work for all users independently. The problem I'm having is when I post to the local storage for one user change and then recall the data, it recalls the data for all users and not just the one that made the change. See example for just one user "David" but keep in mind I have 6 other people on the team. see jsfiddle code here--> http://jsfiddle.net/skippd01/optwxh0d/

```
 <script>
 function foo(a) {
 //alert(a.value);
 var d = new Date();
 var c = document.getElementById("time").innerHTML;
 c = c + a.value + " was selected at: " + d.toString();
 document.getElementById("time").innerHTML = c + '<br/>';
 localStorage.setItem(a.value, d.toString());
 }

 function load() {
 var c = "Wholesale Pictures: " + localStorage.getItem("Wholesale Pictures") + '<br/>';
 c += "NS Pictures:" + localStorage.getItem("NS Pictures") + '<br/>';
 c += "NS ERO's:" + localStorage.getItem("NS ERO's") + '<br/>';
 c += "BL ERO's:" + localStorage.getItem("BL ERO's") + '<br/>';
 c += "Wholesale Staging:" + localStorage.getItem("Wholesale Staging") + '<br/>';
 c += "Wholesale Scan:" + localStorage.getItem("Wholesale Scan") + '<br/>';
 c += "Sirius Tags:" + localStorage.getItem("Sirius Tags") + '<br/>';
 c += "Lunch Break:" + localStorage.getItem("Lunch Break") + '<br/>';
 document.getElementById("log").innerHTML = c;
 }
 </script>

<h2>David</h2>
<p id="log"></p>
```

//this "log" is where the history of the options selected below is displayed after clicking the "Activity Log" button (see below for the button). It also displays the timestamp for the option they select.

```
<select id="options" class="form-control" onchange="foo(this)">
<option>Select Work Area</option>
<option>NS Pictures</option>
<option>NS ERO's</option>
<option>BL ERO's</option>
<option>Wholesale Staging</option>
<option>Wholesale Scan</option>
<option>Wholesale Pictures</option>
<option>Sirius Tags</option>
<option>Lunch Break</option>
</select>

<div class="buttons">
<button id="History" onclick="load()">Activity Log</button>
//I select "Activity Log" to get a daily activity log for "David" in this example.This is the log that is stored in the web browser local storage. 
</div>
<p id="time"><br/></p>
```

//This "time" id is just a real time display of the option the user is selecting from above, and goes away after refresh of screen.

Comment: You want to share "localStorage" with 7 different users (different machines)? In my opinion your question is *unclear what you're asking*. Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking. See the [How to Ask](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page for help clarifying this question.

Comment: I have 7 employees who will be using the same page on our internal website called "Current Assignment" They will simply use a dropdown form and select what they are working on and it will produce a timestamp and I can recall the timestamp from localStorage by clicking "Activity Log".

Comment: They all use the same machine. The problem I'm having is every time one updates their work area, it updates the other employees work area. I need the code to work exclusively for "David" when he selects "Lunch Break" and it would be great if the form dropdown would be able to keep that option even after the page has been refreshed.

Comment: Forgive me, is not possible to understand the purpose of your script. I recommend you read these links: ["How do I ask a good question?"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), ["How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and ["Asking"](http://stackoverflow.com/help/asking)

Comment: The above example is verifiable. I just used it in my HTML page. I have read the links you provided. The example I provided has some comments now that I hope help you, if not then I don't know how else to phrase this question. Doing the best I can.

Comment: You need to explain how users will work using your script. Another tips: improve typing, organize text, use line breaks.

Good writing already helps us better understand your question (as is mentioned in the links that you spent). Hopefully I can help it.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not totally clear on what you're trying to achieve, but I'll take a stab at it.

It sounds like you would like to store each users input (which I can't see here), and keep it discreet.

It seems like you could easily accomplish this by namespacing your localStorage according to the user on save and retrieve. The following would create a wrapper for setItem and getItem.

```
var currentUser = "david";

function setItem(key, value) {
  // namespace by the currentUser, and assuming you'll always pass a string for value
  return localStorage.setItem(currentUser + ":" + key, value);
}

function getItem(key) {
  return localStorage.getItem(currentUser + ":" + key);
}
```

Comment: I am trying to store each users input yes. The inputs are listed under the <select> options "NS Pictures", "NS ERO's" etc. So when a worker selects one of these options it stores it to local storage with a timestamp for each change. I can then recall that storage log and post it on the screen to view what the worker has done for the day along with what time they did the task (ERO's, Pictures, Wholesale etc.)

Comment: ok. I missed the `foo`. I skimmed right over it because it was named `foo`. So assuming you're keeping track of the user, you should be able to namespace your localStorage items to each user. Does the above work?

Comment: Yes, it works. The only way it does for multiple users is by changing the foo to foo1 and foo2 etc. Then I canged the "time" to "time1" and "time2" etc for each block of code if that makes sense. Sorry I'm very new to coding and just learning. I'm sure there is a better way. I would like to dry up the code as much as possible, but for now it's working as is. Where can I get more information on namespace? Never heard of it.

Comment: @DelmasSkipper how do you control which user is entering in the information?

Comment: For now each user has his own block of code (in the example above) along with a drop down form. In order to make it work I had to make each block of code and drop down option just slightly different with numbers and punctuation so they don't interfere with each other. Not very practical...which is why I'm here asking questions. I know there must be a way to use one single block of code that communicates to the local storage and allows for the form controls to be all the same for multiple users. If you like to see the code just tell me how to get the whole page over to you and I'll send it.

Comment: @DelmasSkipper ok. so what determines which block of code is used? Code examples with the user switching would be helpful